# Clip path for SVG on the bottom text is not working. I want to reach it without JavaScript or Smil

Tags: html, css, svg, text, clip-path

Basically the clip path '#path-1' is animated and I want to apply it to the bottom text to reach an typewriter effect. I already made it with SMIL code and it works fine but this SVG is my Logo so I want to upload it in my website and I want that all animations run in most common and frequent web browsers.

That's why I'm trying to performing with CSS only. The SVG code is this:

```html
<svg id="palmdesign-logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1433.04 398.88">
<defs>  
   <clipPath id="path-1">  
     <path class="primarypath" d="M1421.75,395.66H8.58V322H1421.75 z" />  
   </clipPath>
   <clipPath id="path-2">  
     <path class="cls-x" d="M589,287.24H13V48H589Z"/>  
   </clipPath> 
 </defs>
<style>
@font-face {
font-family: 'Dense Regular';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
src: local('Dense Regular'), url('Dense-Regular.woff') format('woff');
}
.cls-1{fill:#3ee7ad; font-family:Dense;font-size:343px; letter-spacing:0.112em;-webkit-animation: slideup 1.5s forwards;
 animation: slideup 1.5s forwards;}
.cls-2{font-size:343px;font-family:Dense-Thin,Dense;font-weight:200;letter-spacing:0.112em;}
.cls-2{stroke-dashoffset: -25%; stroke-dasharray: 50% 0; stroke-width: 0; fill: rgba(62,231,173,1); stroke: rgba(54,95,160,0);animation: stroke 7s 1 forwards ease-in-out; }
.cls-3{fill:#3ee7ad; font-family:Dense;}
.cls-3{font-size:73px; letter-spacing:0.206em;}
.cls-4{fill:#3ee7ad;}

@keyframes stroke {
    0%   {
        fill: rgba(62,231,173,0); stroke: rgba(62,231,173,1);
        stroke-dashoffset: 25%; stroke-dasharray: 0 50%; stroke-width: 4;
    }
    70%  {fill: rgba(62,231,173,0); stroke: rgba(62,231,173,1); }
    80%  {fill: rgba(62,231,173,0); stroke: rgba(62,231,173,1); stroke-width: 2; }
    100% {
        fill: rgba(62,231,173,1); stroke: rgba(54,95,160,0); 
        stroke-dashoffset: -25%; stroke-dasharray: 50% 0; stroke-width: 0;
    }
}
@keyframes slideup {
  0%   {transform: translate(0,450px);}

   100% {transform: translate(0,287px);}
}
/* The typing effect */
@keyframes typing {
  from { transform: scaleX(0);}
  to {transform: scaleX(1);  }
}


@keyframes fade-in {
  from { opacity: 0;}
  to {opacity: 1;}
}
  .primarypath {
      transform: scaleX(0);
  animation: 
    typing 3.5s forwards steps(38);
    animation-delay: 1s;
}
#palmdesign-logo:hover > .cls-2 {
    animation: stroke 7s infinite alternate ease-in-out;    
}

</style>

<text class="cls-1" transform="translate(0 287.26)">PALM</text>
<text class="cls-2" transform="translate(625 287.26)">DESIGN</text>
<text class="cls-3" transform="translate(13.69 385.74)">DESIGN GRÁFICO | WEB DESIGN | MULTIMÉDIA
</text>
</svg>
```

but when I try to link the clip path

```
<clipPath id="path-1">
```

(that is an animated path) to the text

```
<text class="cls-3"
```

doing it in this way

```
<text class="cls-3" transform="translate(13.69 385.74)" clip-path="url(#path-1)">DESIGN GRÁFICO | WEB DESIGN | MULTIMÉDIA
```

the bottom text just disappears. Am I missing something?

Comment: What browsers are you trying to target that support CSS animation but don't support SMIL? Note that Edge is now based on Blink and so now does support SMIL.

Comment: Wrap the text in a group and clip the group. Alternatively delete the transformation of the text and replace it with `x="13.69" y="385.74"`

Comment: as far as i am concerned Robert, MS Edge is not supporting SMIL... I've already upload the SVG with SMIL and that specific animated text is not showing up in the Edge Browser.

Comment: Also please take a look at this pen: https://codepen.io/tmrDevelops/pen/yyprGq Instead of clipping the text you can put it on a path and change the length of the path

Comment: Voilá, enxaneta! You got the solution just a simple ```<g></g>´´´ made all the difference. Thanks!

Comment: That codepen is SMIL code enxaneta. Edge is not accepting that code. That's why i created it with CSS but i was missing something till you helped me :)

Comment: As far as everyone else is concerned MS Edge does support SMIL though.

Answer (score 0):

```css
@font-face {
font-family: 'Dense Regular';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
src: local('Dense Regular'), url('Dense-Regular.woff') format('woff');
}
.cls-1{fill:#3ee7ad; font-family:Dense;font-size:343px; letter-spacing:0.112em;-webkit-animation: slideup 1.5s forwards;
 animation: slideup 1.5s forwards;}
.cls-2{font-size:343px;font-family:Dense-Thin,Dense;font-weight:200;letter-spacing:0.112em;}
.cls-2{stroke-dashoffset: -25%; stroke-dasharray: 50% 0; stroke-width: 0; fill: rgba(62,231,173,1); stroke: rgba(54,95,160,0);animation: stroke 7s 1 forwards ease-in-out; }
.cls-3{fill:#3ee7ad; font-family:Dense;}
.cls-3{font-size:73px; letter-spacing:0.206em;}
.cls-4{fill:#3ee7ad;}

@keyframes stroke {
    0%   {
        fill: rgba(62,231,173,0); stroke: rgba(62,231,173,1);
        stroke-dashoffset: 25%; stroke-dasharray: 0 50%; stroke-width: 4;
    }
    70%  {fill: rgba(62,231,173,0); stroke: rgba(62,231,173,1); }
    80%  {fill: rgba(62,231,173,0); stroke: rgba(62,231,173,1); stroke-width: 2; }
    100% {
        fill: rgba(62,231,173,1); stroke: rgba(54,95,160,0); 
        stroke-dashoffset: -25%; stroke-dasharray: 50% 0; stroke-width: 0;
    }
}
@keyframes slideup {
  0%   {transform: translate(0,450px);}

   100% {transform: translate(0,287px);}
}
/* The typing effect */
@keyframes typing {
  from { transform: scaleX(0);}
  to {transform: scaleX(1);  }
}

@keyframes fade-in {
  from { opacity: 0;}
  to {opacity: 1;}
}
  .primarypath {
      transform: scaleX(0);
  animation: 
    typing 3.5s forwards steps(38);
    animation-delay: 1s;
}
#palmdesign-logo:hover > .cls-2 {
    animation: stroke 7s infinite alternate ease-in-out;    
}
```

```html
<svg id="palmdesign-logo" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1433.04 398.88">
<defs>  
   <clipPath id="path-1">  
     <path class="primarypath" d="M1421.75,395.66H8.58V322H1421.75 z" />  
   </clipPath>
   <clipPath id="path-2">  
     <path class="cls-x" d="M589,287.24H13V48H589Z"/>  
   </clipPath> 
 </defs>
<text class="cls-1" transform="translate(0 287.26)">PALM</text>
<text class="cls-2" transform="translate(625 287.26)">DESIGN</text>
<g id="text-bottom" clip-path="url(#path-1)">
<text class="cls-3" x="13.69" y="385.74">DESIGN GRÁFICO | WEB DESIGN | MULTIMÉDIA
</text>
</g>
</svg>
```